# ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 10) are incompatible

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have 7 categories to classify into, i have used label encoder on my y_train even then i am getting this error and have also converted this to float. Pls look into this problem.[Added the picture of all the shapes required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAWct.png)

```
le = LabelEncoder() 
yy_train=le.fit_transform(y_train)


yy_train=yy_train.astype(float)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(186, input_shape=(180,), activation = 'relu'))

model.add(Dense(256, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.6))

model.add(Dense(128, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')

history = model.fit(X_train, yy_train, batch_size=64, epochs=30)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert yy_train from an array of categories
to an array of binary values indicating the category.

e.g.

```
[1,3,10,6]
-->
[
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]
]
```

.

```
n = len(yy_train)
YY_train = np.zeros(n,10)
for i in range(n):
    YY_train[i,yy_train[i]-1] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for replying ,but my yy_train should not have binary values as i am classifying it into one of the 7 different categories , so pls let me know if the same solution applys or a different one.

Comment: Check more carefully my solution pls. Each item in yy_train is a an array of 10 positions with the value of one in the position of the category

Comment: Thanks a lot Christos Palyvos for helping me and i really appreciate the effort the model is running successfully. I just have a small doubt the last layer in the model.add(Dense(10,) , should i add 7 since i am classifying it into 7 different categories? or should i leave it at 10? thank you so much for the help!!!

Comment: You should have 7.